# Show cursor at particular position on Edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an application in which I am using a multi-line `EditText` whose width and height both are match_parent that takes whole screen size. Now if user clicks or touches on particular position of `EditText`, the cursor should visible at that particular position  and user can start typing from that particular position.

I had search google and developers.android for this type of property in `EditText` class but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `editText1.setSelection(index)` which will position your caret to the specific position you want it to be.

The **index** is the position where you want to place the `caret` based of character array of string.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Buddy but you have not understood my question properly, i want to make cursor visible at a position where user clicks which independent of  array of string.